# Solution to Harmonic oscillator equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I always listen about solution for harmonic oscillator, as a linear combination of sines and cosines, but never have seen how can be solved by integration directly. The equation is:

$$F=ma=m{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}=m{\ddot {x}}=-kx.$$

or shortly: $$m{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}=-kx.$$

Can you show how to obtain x(t) from the second formula (by integration, as i said in first paragraph)?
I couldn't find it in web.

Comment: Comment on question v1: I'd recommend working on your web searching skills.

Comment: @joshphysics show one link so, your comment does not help

Comment: I literally typed the title of your question into the Google search bar, and the first link is the following which contains a slide with precisely what you're looking for: https://www.ncsu.edu/crsc/events/ugw05/slides/root_harmonic.pdf

Comment: @joshphysics i think you do not understand why i asked. I have read that article. Please, read the post again or dont bother. And look at the slide number 7 of your pdf link

Comment: I'm quite sure I understand your question.  Look at the slide(s) on the characteristic equation -- this is the systematic way to solve linear, homogeneous ODEs with constant coefficients.

Comment: No, i am asking how to solve it by integration.That is not explained in the pdf. @joshphysics

Comment: In that case you need to define what you mean by "solve by integration."  This is not a separable ODE, so it cannot be solved by somehow manipulating the terms and then integrating both sides with respect to time.  In general, "integrating" a differential equation is often taken to mean solving the differential equation -- you're just going to have to remain satisfied with the linear algebraic method.

Comment: Read the first paragraph. I think i was clear and the first person who answered understood it quite well. @joshphysics. You are not helping me, really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit4:** See edit3 for a possible solution. It seems I was initially wrong.

This is an equation who's solution can't be found by direct analytical integration. It requires some knowledge of the $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions. It's typically solved by guess and check, which is an alright method thanks to uniqueness theorems in ODEs.

It can however be solved via other methods, like Fubini's method where we presume that the solution has a taylor expansion.

$x(t) = \sum_n a_n t^n$

**Edit:** The reason it cannot be solved directly is that our analytical tools don't let us solve equations in that way. They lead to an identity that we don't understand, so we have to figure it out in another form. It can be solved from the ODE directly if you use numerical methods.

**Edit2:** Apply two integrations we then find that if $v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$,

$$m(v(t) - v(0)) = -k\int_0^t x(t')dt'$$

Doing that again leads to

$$
m \left(x(t) - x(0) - v(0)t\right) = -k\int_0^t\int_0^{t'} x(t'')dt'' dt' 
$$

Rewriting in terms of $x$

$x(t) = v(0)t + x(0) + -\frac km \int_0^t\int_0^{t'} x(t'')dt'' dt'$

At this point, it isn't clear what function satisfies this solution especially since it is recursive. However, note that it can be done numerically, because the value of $x$ at time $t$ is dependent on the position of all times before then.

**Edit3:** I wonder, if we can solve it via direct integration, try substituting the solution back in infinitely many times.

$$x(t) = v(0)t + x(0) + -\frac km \int_0^t\int_0^{t'} v(0)t'' + x(0) + \left(-\frac km \int_0^{t''}\int_0^{t'''} x(t'''')dt'''' dt'''\right)dt'' dt'$$

is one substitution. If you try it repeatedly, and then ignore the last term, you might actually get the right solution by direct integration.

It looks like what would pop out is

$$x(t) = \frac{v(0)}{\omega}\sin(\omega t) + x(0)\cos(\omega t)$$

where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac km}$. The sines and cosines show up only if you know the taylor expansions, but it seems that you can solve it by direct integration...

Comment: This is what i was asking. Why can not be found directly?

Comment: @HernanProust How do you propose we find it directly?

Comment: @HernanProust I edited it. Does that answer you're question?

Comment: @JMac by integration, that's what i am asking...

Comment: @collegefishies i was trying to solve it by integrations. I do not understand why it can't be solved analitycally. Where is the problem if one tries it? I dont know if i am clear. Anyway the answer has helped

Comment: @HernanProust That last edit should answer it. You shouldn't start flamewars with professors by the way. Not a useful skill. Please accept if it answers your question.

Comment: @HernanProust I think you can solve it via direct integration actually. Check edit3, I left out a lot of detail but I'm sure you can take it from where I started!

Comment: Please don't add in "edit" to your post when making edits. Just add in the additional details (hopefully smoothly) and let the edit history alert those interested parties in the edit trail.